# Is it possible to create a Bluetooth (BLE) custom Service and Characteristic for the smartphone using react-native?

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have to create a custom Service and Characteristic on the smartphone so the peripheral device could write into these new smartphone characteristic. Is this possible using react-native-ble-plx? Is it possible to monitor the managers characteristics? Is there an example of this?

I've already monitored the peripheral devices characteristic successfully, but some developers told me that the communication is faster when you monitor your own characteristic.

Comment: Did you find any way to create your service? I think libraries like  react-native-ble-plx is just for scanning and connecting not for creating services.